# ode45 Matlab NaN appears after a certain elapsed time

Tags: matlab

Hi I'm using ode45 on matlab to solve for position against time and after a certain elapsed time NaN appears as my position values. However, when I try it by copy pasting the last non NaN value into the functions I do get results, and not NaN. In order to find out where it could maybe come from I split the ode45 in two ode45 with the first going from t0 to the time where the problem started and the second one doing the remaining time. The first ode45 worked fine, and the second just output values for the the first two times, so one more position than in the case where I was using just one ode45 although I effectively did not change anything.

Comment: We can't really help without seeing your code. `NaN` commonly occurs because of either `0/0`, `Inf/Inf`, or `Inf-Inf`. Your system may be unstable, you may have a bug, or it *may* be possible rearrange the order of operations to avoid those cases.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you why this is happening. But you should be able to figure it out if you manually run

```
dbstop in FILENAME if naninf
```

Which will break out into the debugger when a NaN appears.